# UE4: find and loop through tagged components (in blueprint)

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have multiple sprite components on an Unreal Engine 4 scene, all of them are added realtime with different tags (to the same blueprint).

How I can find and loop through components with a specific tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **GetComponentsByTag** node for this purpose.